# $\lim_{x\to 3^+} [\frac{5^x-x^5}{2^x-x^2}]=?$

Tags: limits

fine the limit :

$$\lim_{x\to 3^+} [\frac{5^x-x^5}{2^x-x^2}]=?$$

$[x]:$ floor function .

in :https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=%5Clim_%7Bx%5Cto+3%5E%2B%7D+%5Clfloor%5Cfrac%7B5%5Ex-x%5E5%7D%7B2%5Ex-x%5E2%7D%5Crfloor

but Not answer !

Comment: Why the complete lack of personal input? (No, typing formulas in WA does not count as such...)

Answer (score 2):

The function evaluates to 118 at 3. We can check the slope is positive and hence approaching from the right with the floor function yields 118. The following plot illustrates this situation.

[image]

One can check the derivative at 3 is 
$$405+118 (8 \log (2)-6)-125 \log (5) \approx 150.151 > 0 
$$

Answer (score 0):

In
$f(x)
=\frac{5^x-x^5}{2^x-x^2}
$,
let
$x = 3+y$.

Then

$\begin{array}\\
f(3+y)
&=\dfrac{5^{3+y}-(3+y)^5}{2^{3+y}-(3+y)^2}\\
&=\dfrac{125\cdot 5^{y}-(243+5\cdot 81 y+O(y^2))}{8\cdot 2^{y}-(9+6y+y^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{125(1+y\ln 5+O(y^2))-(243+405 y+O(y^2))}{8\cdot (1+y\ln 2+O(y^2))-(9+6y+y^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{-118+y(\ln 5 -405)+O(y^2)}{-1+y(\ln 2+6)+O(y^2)}\\
&=\dfrac{118+y(405-\ln 5)+O(y^2)}{1-y(\ln 2+6)+O(y^2)}\\
&=(118+y(405-\ln 5)+O(y^2))(1+y(\ln 2+6)+O(y^2))\\
&=118+y(405-\ln 5+118(\ln 2+6))+O(y^2))\\
\end{array}
$

As $y \to 0^+$,
$f(3+y) \to 118+$,
so the result,
as Nick R stated,
is $118$.